# Why might IE 11 render a blank page despite apparently throwing no errors?

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Several months back I built the following website: www.dcpartnersre.com

Everything looks as it should on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

It's come to my attention that the page, for whatever reason, is displaying only the topbar and the rest is completely blank in Internet Explorer 11. I've been able to reproduce this multiple times.

Upon investigation, all I found were several warnings, including:

```
DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "<!DOCTYPE html>".
Character reference is missing an ending semicolon ";".
```

What might be the cause of this error, and what might be a viable approach to fixing it?

Please excuse my lack of familiarity with Windows/IE development, and I appreciate your help!

I've attached a screenshot below for clarity:

[image: Just the topbar – all else is blank!]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, IE is looking for a tag at the top of your file that looks like `<!DOCTYPE html>`. If you add that to the top of your file, the error should go away.

EDIT: Above might fix the first warning. The real error is probably the Character reference issue.

Comment: @Murtaza Thanks for the quick reply. Would warnings as (seemingly) trivial as those really cause the document to break in this way?

Comment: no i don't think so.  I just noticed that you attached a picture and both issues are WARNINGS, not errors.  Are you comfortable with the developer console in IE.  Try looking at the HTML elements and see where they 'disappeared' to.